# JSON.parse fails to create an object from a string

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I am using ruby on rails to create a cookie that returns an array containing the params of the request back to the view as a string. However, I get the following error when I JSON.parse that string:

```
JSON.parse('%7B%22specialty%22%3A%5B%22Anesthesiology%22%5D%7D')

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0
```

how do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string is not valid json.

It is uri encoded so decode it using [`decodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

```
JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent('%7B%22specialty%22%3A%5B%22Anesthesiology%22%5D%7D'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `decodeURIComponent` to first decode the string.

```
JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(
  '%7B%22specialty%22%3A%5B%22Anesthesiology%22%5D%7D'
));
```

As the string is encoded.  Once you decode it, you get the key value pair, i.e. the object in the form of a string.  Now you can use `JSON.parse` to form the Javascript object.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are correct in saying that the payload is URI encoded, but `decodeURIComponent` is only a javascript method. To decode it ruby-side, use [`URI.unescape`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html#method-i-unescape).

```
JSON.parse(URI.unescape('%7B%22specialty%22%3A%5B%22Anesthesiology%22%5D%7D'))
```

You say you're using rails, so the URI object should already be available, but if you weren't using rails you would need to `require 'uri'` first.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError:` is likely a javascript error.